Rigorous interpretation of the generalized variance
Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$ be a $d\text{-}$dimensional, square-integrable random vector, and let $\Sigma$ denote its covariance matrix. The quantity $\det(\Sigma)$ is known in statistics as the generalized variance of $X$, and is often presented as measuring the squared volume of the typical support of $X$. I was wondering if there was any way to turn this vague claim into a rigorous statement, ideally under the following form: for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a Borel set $K\subseteq{\mathbb R}^d$ such that:

${\mathbb P}(X\in K)\ge 1-\varepsilon$

$\operatorname{Vol(K)}\le C_\varepsilon \sqrt{\det(\Sigma)}$,


where $\operatorname{Vol}$ denotes the $d\text{-}$dimensional Lebesgue measure and where $C_\varepsilon$ is some universal function of $\varepsilon$ (independent of $X$ and $d$).

$\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\Si\Sigma\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$By an orthogonal transformation and a parallel translation (which preserve the volume), without loss of generality $EX=0$ and $\Si$ is a diagonal matrix, with $\si_1^2,\dots,\si_d^2$ on the diagonal, where the $\si_j$'s are positive real numbers.
For real $\ep>0$, let now
$$K_\ep:=\prod_{j=1}^d(-t_\ep\si_j,t_\ep\si_j),$$
where $t_\ep:=\sqrt{d/\ep}$. Then, by the union and Markov's inequalities,
$$P(X\notin K_\ep)=P\big(\max_{j=1}^d(X_j/\si_j)\ge t_\ep\big)
\le\sum_{j=1}^d P(X_j/\si_j\ge t_\ep)\le d/t_\ep^2=\ep.$$
Also, the volume of $K_\ep$ is $(2t_\ep)^d\prod_{j=1}^d\si_i=C_\ep\sqrt{\det\Si}$, where $C_\ep:=(2t_\ep)^d=2^d(d/\ep)^{d/2}$. $\quad\Box$

It is clear that $C_\ep$ must depend on $d$. Indeed, suppose that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed over the interval $J:=[-1,1]$. Then
$$1-\ep\le P(X\in K_\ep)=2^{-d}|K_\ep\cap J^d|\le 2^{-d}|K_\ep|,$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the $d$-volume. Also, here $\det\Si=3^{-d}$. So,
$$|K_\ep|\ge(1-\ep)(2\sqrt3)^d\sqrt{\det\Si} $$
and hence $C_\ep\ge(2\sqrt3)^d$.

Sure, but your $C_\varepsilon$ depends on $d$!

@DRJ : What makes you think you can do without $d$? There are very few inequalities for $\Bbb R^d$ that do not involve $d$. In your problem, it should be pretty clear that dependence on $d$ cannot be avoided -- think e.g. of the case when the $X_i$'s are i.i.d. uniformly distributed over the interval $[-1,1]$.

@DRJ : I have now added a piece showing that $C_\ep$ must depend on $d$.

(The Muse has commanded me to write this answer in a style somewhat like that of a textbook. You've been warned.)
The "covariance matrix" $\Sigma$ is so called because its $i,j$ entry is $\operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)$ (so that its diagonal entries are variances). But some people prefer to call it the variance $\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{var}\big((X_1,\ldots,X_d)^T\big)$ of the random vector $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_d)^T$ because when $\mu= \operatorname E(X)$ then
$$
\Sigma = \operatorname E\big((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T \big) \in \mathbb R^{d\times d}.
$$
From this it follows that if $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times d}$ then
$$
\operatorname{var}(AX) = A\Sigma A^T \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}.
$$
In particular, for a column vector $a\in\mathbb R^{d\times1},$ the variance of the scalar-valued random variable $a^TX$ is the scalar $a^T\Sigma a\ge 0.$ That proves that the "covariance matrix" is positive-semi-definite.
When the real symmetric matrix $\Sigma$ is diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $G,$ getting $\Sigma=G^T\Lambda G,$ we therefore see that all of the diagonal entries are nonnegative. And are variances of certain linear combinations of the scalar components of $X.$
Replacing all of those variances on the diagonal of $\Lambda$ with standard deviations, the square roots of the variances, yields $\Sigma^{1/2} = G^T\Lambda^{1/2} G,$ another positive-semi-definite real symmetric matrix. Now observe that when $\Sigma$ is nonsingular we have:
$$
\operatorname{var}(Y) =\operatorname{var}\left( \Sigma^{-1/2} X\right) = I_d,
$$
the $d\times d$ identity matrix (where the first equality above defines the random vector $Y$). This is analogous to dividing a real-valued random variable by its standard deviation to get one whose standard deviation is $1.$
The components of $Y$ are uncorrelated and each has variance $1.$
Exercise: Use the ideas above to show that every positive-semi-definite real symmetric matrix is the variance of some random vector.
Now consider two situations:
1. $\qquad Y_1, \ldots, Y_d \sim \text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(0,1).$
In this case $\Pr(\|Y\|\le r) = \Pr\left(\chi^2_d\le r^2\right).$
 Exercise:  Show that when $\Sigma$ is singular one need only replace $d$ with the (smaller) rank of $\Sigma$ in the line above.
Exercise: What does that say about the answer to the question?
2. $\qquad$ No assumptions about the joint distribution of the scalar components of $Y$ are made beyond what is given above: they are uncorrelated, homoskedastic with variance $1,$ and all have expectation $0.$
Then we can apply Chebyshev's inequality to each $Y_i.$ But since they are not assumed independent, we can't just raise probabilities to the power $d.$ Thus one should do some reasoning that parallels the proof of Chebyshev's inequality, but involves matrix algebra (in which the order of multiplication matters).
